# Merge and sort JSON arrays

Tags: json, jq

I have problem with jq.
From API I received following data:

```
{
  "items": [4,5,1,3,2],
  "objectNumbers": [
     {
        "type": "objectNumber",
        "number": 8
     },
     {
        "type": "objectNumber",
        "number": 7
     },
     {
        "type": "objectNumber",
        "number": 10
     },
     {
        "type": "objectNumber",
        "number": 6
     },
     {
        "type": "objectNumber",
        "number": 9
     }
  ]
}
```

Using jq I want create new objects from items array, merge it with objectNumbers and sort it using number. In this moment, I have new objects from items:

```
jq '.items[] | {type: "itemNumber", number: .}'
```

but I don't know how can I merge it with objectNumbers. Finally, I want follwing structure:

```
...
     {
        "type": "itemNumber",
        "number": 4
     },
     {
        "type": "itemNumber",
        "number": 5
     },
     {
        "type": "objectNumber",
        "number": 6
     },
     {
        "type": "objectNumber",
        "number": 7
     },
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. Just put your script's products into an array, add it to `objectNumbers` and sort by `number` field. E.g.:

```
[.items[] | {type: "itemNumber", number: .}] + .objectNumbers
| sort_by(.number)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/pF4kKgX38c)</sup>